# Чтение строк с клавиатуры в Debug режиме. Intellij IDEA, Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, отладка

При достижении строки, в которой происходит считывание данных с клавиатуры я перехожу во вкладку Console и ввожу там строку, нажимаю Enter, ничего не происходит. Команды F7 F8 с этого момента тоже перестают работать. Очевидно, программа ожидает ввода текста, поэтому дальше не пускает. Но ведь я его ввёл! В общем помогите разобраться, как в debug режиме считать строку с консоли!
P.s. когда ввожу текст, буквы при вводе перемешиваются (скачет курсор). Например когда ввожу QWERTY, отображает QEWTRY

```
public class Debug {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

        System.out.println("TestLine");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = reader.readLine(); // breakpoint, здесь прога вечно ждёт ввода
        System.out.println(line); // breakpoint, эта строка никогда не будет выведена
    }
}
```

Comment: Продублировал все то, что вы описали, все отработало. Может что то забыли указать вы?

Comment: Создаю новый проект, создаю класс, вставляю этот код, компилирую, всё работает как нужно.  
Ставлю брейкпоинты. Запускаю в режиме дебага. И опять когда дохожу до строки в которой происходит считывание с клавиатуры -  ввожу текст, буквы при вводе перемешиваются (скачет курсор), нажимаю Enter, ничего не происходит. Команды F7 F8 с этого момента тоже перестают работать. Java 13.0.2, Intellij IDEA 2020.1

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, переустановив JDK и IDE (openJDK 14.0.1, Intellij IDEA 2020.1)